# Issue with Assembly Code: Program Crashes at movb store to stack memory (%esp)

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, segmentation-fault, stack-memory

I am currently learning assembly and I am trying to write a simple program. I have the following code:

```
.global do_main

.section .text
do_main:
    sub $4, %esp
    movb $'H', (%esp)
    movb $'e', 1(%esp)
    movb $'y', 2(%esp)
    movb $'!', 3(%esp)
    mov $4, %eax
    mov $1, %ebx
    mov %esp, %ecx
    mov $1, %edx
    int $0x80
    mov $1, %eax
    mov $0, %ebx
    int $0x80
```

However, the program crashes at the movb instructions where I try to move characters onto the stack. I have watched tutorials on YouTube that use similar code, but for some reason, it doesn't work for me.

Can someone help me understand why my program is crashing at these specific instructions? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you assemble this into a 64-bit executable?  If so, `sub $4, %esp` truncates 64-bit RSP to 32-bit, producing a value that doesn't point to a valid page.  You're using 32-bit `int 0x80` system calls as well as stack pointer, so you should assemble this with `gcc -m32` or `as --32` on a normal 64-bit system where the default is `-m64` / `--64`.

Comment: @PeterCordes can I keep assemble on my default and just modify ````sub $4, %esp````?

Comment: No.  The 32-bit `int 0x80` system-call ABI only supports 32-bit args, so it only works for pointers in the low 32 bits of virtual address-space.  (Which doesn't include the stack) [What happens if you use the 32-bit int 0x80 Linux ABI in 64-bit code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46087730) .  You could `sub $8, %rsp` and `movb ..., (%rsp)` if you want to write 64-bit code.